# Как использовать HLS Lib?

Tags: javascript, hls

Хочу воспроизвести mp4 фильм в потоке, но видео просто грузится (скачивается), на маленьких видео оно сразу воспроизводит. Как решить эту проблему, чтобы большие видео тоже сразу воспроизводились но в потоке? Вот код:

```
<video id="video" controls></video>
```

```
var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var videoSrc = 'https://cloud.cdnland.in/f31a7101adaa8b612a4d58714562ca57:2024010306/showtvseries/f017807dcada883c2dfbe7da3fe529ce71792526/720.mp4';
  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
  }
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = videoSrc;
  }
```

Comment: Так mp4 это не hls. И этот файл прекрасно воспроизводится напрямую в теге `<video>` без использования всяких неуместных библиотек

Comment: Не знаешь - молчи. Это видео в потоке никак не будет воспроизводится и всегда будет тормозить

Comment: Я прекрасно знаю, потому что я это проверил перед написанием своего комментария — всё прекрасно воспроизводится, и даже перемотка работает и не тормозит

Comment: Жду пруфы от тебя

Comment: Пока вы чего-то ждали целую неделю, показанная вами ссылка уже перестала работать и нынче отдаёт ошибку 404